# How to unmounting component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to reset state in the component what can I do??
how to set default value in state it write it but doesn't work

```js
useEffect(() => { 
   dispatch(
        setMapStateAction({
          searchCity: '',
          searchLocation: '',
          showSearchCityResult: false,
          showSearchLocationResult: false,
          selectedCity: {
            id: defaultViewPort.id,
            name: defaultViewPort.name,
            lat: defaultViewPort.latitude,
            lng: defaultViewPort.longitude,
          },
          viewport: {
            latitude: 35.69976003841564,
            longitude: 51.33808390275898,
          },
        })
      );
   }, []);
```

Comment: The easiest way to format code, is to make sure to have 4 spaces before each line that you want to have formatted. A tab is also fine. Feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your state in you redux reducer/slice not in a useEffect of a React component.

```
const initialState = { searchCity: '', searchLocation: '', ...etc}


const mapSlice= createSlice({
  name: 'map',
  initialState,
  reducers: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset your state when component unmount you have to dispatch action in useEfect return fuction
for an example

```
    useEffect(() => { 
    
// whatever you write in return function it will run after coponent unmount
    return () = >{
       dispatch(
            setMapStateAction({
              searchCity: '',
              searchLocation: '',
              showSearchCityResult: '',
              showSearchLocationResult: '',
              selectedCity: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                lat: '',
                lng: '',
              },
              viewport: {
                latitude: '',
                longitude: '',
              },
            })
          )
    }
       }, [])

;
```